# Is it possible to have smaller $R^2$ value after transformation of data?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I recently perform a transformation on a multiple linear regression model using Box-Cox method (more precisely, the `powerTransform` function in R).

However, as I use `power` in the summary to adjust my model, I find that the model after transformation has a smaller $R^2$ (and adjusted $R^2$) compared with the original.

Is it possible to get such a result or did I do something wrong here?

Comment: It's happened to you and anything you used in R will be trustworthy, so no mistake is likely. I can't see your data or exactly what you did but "improving" the marginal distribution of one variable (e.g. bringing it closer to normality or at least symmetry) isn't guaranteed to "improve" $R^2$. For example, you might be suppressing an outlier which boosted the $R^2$. For one predictor, comparing scatter plots before and after is essential. More generally, plot your data to see what changed. Looking at adjusted $R^2$ does not change the principle.

Comment: On behalf of Coxes everywhere, and with every positive feeling about Boxes too, please name Box and Cox correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but I just copy the slide and code from my professor, she says it is called a boxCox method In R, I don't quite know what's wrong with this expression:)

Comment: Perhaps not, but a little rummaging around shows that the procedure was introduced by G.E.P. Box and D.R. Cox. My (small) point was partly self-reference (I  have the same name as, but am not related to, Sir David Cox) and partly that people's family names should be rendered correctly.

Comment: It sounds like you transformed the response (dependent) variable (in which case it makes little sense to compare the two kinds of $R^2$). Is this inference correct?